Present tense - if there are a few options for the sentence
I've enrolled in a language course and the teacher gave me a sentence she can't explain herself. The sentence is:

And they (to do) density, new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now.

I think that either the present simple, continuous, or perfect can be used because we lack enough information to make a straightforward choice. Do I understand correctly that the adverbial phrase "right now" DOES NOT modify the main clause, but refers to the abstract people, therefore we can't say that we must use only the Present Continuous here. (I personally love infinitive more, because it works as a fact that someone "does density")
I also asked what she meant by "to do density", as it sounds rather uncanny, but she didn't give an answer. I think for it to sound right it should be followed by another noun (Like in "to do density calculations").
Thank you in advance!

Does doing density mean calculating density or something like that? If so, they're doing density, but that sounds unusual, dumbed-down for some reason. 'Do the density!' Who says that, scientists without social skills? Mammography supervisors in a hurry? I don't get it.

Unfortunately, the teacher didn't give me an answer. I still want to know if it's possible to use the present simple in this part (they do), and if "right know" modifyes the main clause, because I think it describes specifically the comparative adverbial phrase, not the main clause. I may be wrong, this is why I want to be certain.

If I only knew... The teacher asked me to put a verb in the right tense, but the sentence itself sounds strange and raises confusion about which tense is better to use. My teacher said that because we have "right now" at the end it means that it's the Present Cont, but it does not modify the main clause, if I understand it correctly. So I wanted to ask if we can use other tenses here, and if I'm right that "right now" does not modify the main clause, because it provides information on another thing (people).

Almost certainly the present simple is the correct choice, informed (though not demanded) by the 'right now'. The present continuous construction (it's not a tense in the strict sense) is not unacceptable. But I agree that 'do' is in an incongruous register. Perhaps 'cover[s]' or 'address[es]'. I'm afraid that, like HSU and W V, I have to say the question is poor.

Could you please formulate the best version of this sentence? I'd be very grateful! And it seems like I should drop this course, as the teacher doesn't understand what she teaches... :(

This is part of a TED talk given in 2005 by Alex Steffen: “ Here, for example, is Vancouver, which if you haven't been there, you ought to go for a visit. It's a fabulous city. And they are doing density, new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now.”

Oh, I see, thank you so much. But if there is no context, is it possible to use "And they do new density (instead of "are doing"), new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now", or any other tense, or there's only one correct option? My answer was "they do density" because I didn't have enough context, and I decided it was a fact.

Also, Xanne, could please explain me what does the expression "to do density" mean in this context. I don't exactly understand (maybe you can give me some synonym if it's possible, too).

Either “are doing” or “do” works in the sentence as quoted.
This is part of a TED talk given in 2007 by Alex Steffen https://www.ted.com/talks/alex_steffen_the_route_to_a_sustainable_future/transcript?subtitle=en:

Here, for example, is Vancouver, which if you haven't been there, you ought to go for a visit. It's a fabulous city. And they are doing density, new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now.

“Doing density” appears to refer to how the city is managing the concentration of population.
“Do” is a very flexible verb. For example:

My housekeeper doesn’t do windows.


He teaches history but he doesn’t do ancient Greece.


He is teaching world history this semester but he isn’t doing the Far East.


A more informal use: I like people, but I don’t do sympathy.

In the given example the present continuous works best, but the simple present is also acceptable.
Some comments suggest that this use of “to do” is informal, and I agree. The entire TED talk from which the quotation is informal.

Thank you so much! You're my saviour. So it means that it wasn't wrong to use the present simple, especially If I wasn't given enough context?

I don’t think you were wrong.

Edit after Xanne's comment of the source.
"Doing density" is informal speech and should not be copied unless the exam requests the vernacular. I suggest that a more formal sentence could be

And they are implementing [urban] density, new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now.


I didn't get the task at first, which after some discussion seems to be

Replace (to do) with a word.

So I offer, in the simple present tense,

And they understand density, new density, better than probably anybody else on the planet right now.

However I don't know whether "new density" is a thing, or a concept in science.

Sorry if I didn't make it clear enough. The task is to conjugate the verb "do" in the correct tense (for example: they do density, they are doing density, they have done density, etc). This is the way how tasks are usually structured for foreign learners.

If the teacher does not understand the task, are you certain? And what then, is "new density"?

As I understand the teacher just found this sentence on the internet and doesn't undertsand what it means herself. However, she insist that there's only one correct answer, and it's "are doing density". My asnwer was "they do density". Now I want to understand which tense is better to use here, or this sentence doesn't make sense at all in order to conjugate the verb correctly, And of course if my answer is acceptable in terms of tenses (they do density).

"Do density / football / drugs" is an informal expression to mean "study / play /take". How can it be used as a comparison with the rest of the planet's population? It's an action statement.

This is her reply: "This is the present continuous tense describing an ongoing action happening now".
I don't agree with that because how can we know that it's the present continuous tense, but not the present simple. If I understand it correctly, the adverbial phrase "right know" at the end doesn't modify "they", but "people who do something right know" in the first place, this is why we can't know if "they" do it right know, or they do it regurarly, or they finished doing it. I need some argumentation.

About the informal expression "do density". Thank you for letting me know, could you provide me an example of how it can be used correctly in a sentence?

"Right now" isn't continuous.

The theory says that "right now" is the time marker for present cont. Here's the quote:
Time markers.
These words/phrases are used to indicate the time of present continuous verbs:
now,
right now,
at the moment,
at present,
at the present time,
presently,
currently,
for the time being,
these days,
nowadays,
today, this month, this year, etc.

Sorry, I can't agree with all those. 'Now' might be continuous, but 'Right now' emphasizes the present moment.
